# How do I create responsive card columns whilst templating with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a responsive 'smart home' web app.

To make the app more responsive to larger screens, I want to split up the room and light cards into columns - 2 columns for tablets (lg) and 3 columns for desktops (xl).

This is what the app looks like on xs an s displays (mobile):
[image]

This is what I want the cards to look like on lg:
[image]

I'm loading all data from a JSON file and creating a card for each room and light like this:

```
$.each(rooms_data, function (index, obj) {
template = 
    `
    <div class="card" style="background-color: #6e6e6e;">
        <div class="card-body" data-cardid="${obj.id}">
            ` + html_favourite_light + `
            <h6 class="card-title" style="color: #d1d1d1;">Room: ${obj.room}</h6>
            <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2" style="color: #ffffff;">${obj.name}</h5>
            <p style="color: #ffffff;">Rating:` + html_rating_light + `</p style="color: #ffffff;">
            <select class="custom-select mb-3" id="sel1" style="background-color: #696969; border: none; color: #ffffff;">
                <option>${obj.select_1}</option>
                <option>${obj.select_2}</option>
                <option>${obj.select_3}</option>
                <option>${obj.select_4}</option>
            </select>
            ` + html_switch_light + `
            <h5 class="card-text pt-2" style="color: white;">Main Switch</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})
```

I've tried it with card decks and card groups, but I have never gotten the right result until now.